# How to stop my pet from chewing on everything

Tags: training, multi-pet-families, chewing

My Pet has turned 1 year old but her chewing everything habit is not going. If kept loose she eat up almost everything(wood, plant, cloth, plastic, chair sheet etc.). Everybody is fedup and I'm trying to find ways to stop her this habit. Is there any deficiency of something in her or any vaccination or any medicine is required for this. At-least her this habit gets minimized.

Comment: What kind of pet? Dog? Cat? Something else?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to stop dog chewing things](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/6209/how-to-stop-dog-chewing-things)

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your dog (assuming your pet is a dog, because if it were an iguana it probably wouldn't be able to chew up the chair covers) is bored, and destroying things is a fun way to pass the time.

Things to consider:

*Does your dog have appropriate things to chew on?*

- Some good options are a [Himalayan Dog Chew](http://amzn.to/2oZoaPa), [Benebone](http://amzn.to/2oZwyyi), or [rope toys](http://amzn.to/2pGVEQA).  You'll want to supervise your dog when you introduce these toys to make sure your pup won't accidentally break them and/or hurt themselves.

*Does your dog have enough enrichment/mental stimulation?*

- A stuffed [Kong](http://amzn.to/2oODOwz) does wonders to occupy and tire out a bored dog.  Mix your dogs regular kibble with applesauce, peanut butter, etc and use that instead of a bowl at mealtime.  You might also think about a training class.  Lots of dogs enjoy learning and this can provide much needed stimulation as well (search for a training club near you [here](https://webapps.akc.org/obedience-training-club/#/)).